# C# Web Form: GridView disappears while MessageBox is showing

Tags: forms, gridview, web, tabs

I have 3 GridViews, each inside a separate tab. Every row in the GridView is associated with a LinkButton, and when it's clicked a MessageBox are popping up, showing the content on that particular row.

The problem is that when the MessageBox pops up the GridView disappears, and when MessageBox is closed GridView then comes back.

This problem doesn't occur if GridView is used without any tabs and is placed outside the TabControl. Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl TheTabCtrl = new TabControl("InfoTabCtrl");

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            GridView newGridView = new GridView();
            //generate dynamic id        
            newGridView.ID = String.Concat("GridView", i);
            newGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            newGridView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(OnRowDataBound);

            //if (!this.IsPostBack)
            //{
                BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                bfield.HeaderText = "Id";
                bfield.DataField = "Id";
                newGridView.Columns.Add(bfield);

                bfield = new BoundField();
                bfield.HeaderText = "Name";
                bfield.DataField = "Name";
                newGridView.Columns.Add(bfield);

                TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
                tfield.HeaderText = "Country";
                newGridView.Columns.Add(tfield);

                tfield = new TemplateField();
                tfield.HeaderText = "View";
                newGridView.Columns.Add(tfield);
            //}
                this.BindGrid(newGridView, i);

                string myString = i.ToString();
                TabPage BasicPage1 = new TabPage(myString, myString);
                BasicPage1.Controls.Add(newGridView);
                TheTabCtrl.Tabs.Add(BasicPage1);
        }

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string value = Request.Form[TheTabCtrl.Id + "_SelectedTab"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                try
                {
                    TheTabCtrl.SelectedTab = TheTabCtrl.Tabs.IndexOf(TheTabCtrl.Tabs.Where(x => x.Id == value).First());
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        form1.Controls.Add(TheTabCtrl.GetControl);

    }

    private void BindGrid(GridView newGridView, int id)
    {
        string[][,] jaggedArray = new string[3][,] 
        {
            new string[,] { {"John Hammond", "United States"}, {"Mudassar Khan", "India"}, {"Suzanne Mathews", "France"}, {"Robert Schidner", "Russia"} },
            new string[,] { {"Zoey Melwick", "New Zeeland"}, {"Bryan Robertson", "England"}, {"Beth Stewart", "Australia"}, {"Amanda Rodrigues", "Portugal"} },
            new string[,] { {"Glenda Becker", "Germany"}, {"Despoina Athanasiadis", "Greece"}, {"Alexandra López", "Spain"}, {"David Bouchard", "Canada"} }
        };

        for (int row = 0; row < jaggedArray.Length; row++)
        {
            if (id != row) continue;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // Share the same headlines
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });

            for (int pair = 0; pair < jaggedArray[row].Length / 2; pair++)
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(pair + 1, jaggedArray[row][pair, 0], jaggedArray[row][pair, 1]);
            }

            string myPage = string.Concat(row, "page");
            string myString = row.ToString();

            newGridView.DataSource = dt;
            newGridView.DataBind();

        }//End for Row                 

    }//BindGrid

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txtCountry = new TextBox();
            txtCountry.ID = "txtCountry";
            txtCountry.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Country"].ToString();

            e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 200;
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtCountry);

            LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
            lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
            lnkView.Text = "View";

            lnkView.Click += ViewDetails;

            lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Id"].ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnkView);

        }
    }

    protected void ViewDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton);
        GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
        string id = lnkView.CommandArgument;
        string name = row.Cells[1].Text;
        string country = (row.FindControl("txtCountry") as TextBox).Text;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Id: " + id + " Name: " + name + " Country: " + country + "')", true);
    }
```

So how can I show a MessageBox without GridView disappearing?